# jquery tabs in ajax mode change source

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I am trying to change a source of a particular jquery tab (ajax mode) I created. I have 5 tabs now so when the user clicks on the second tab after 50 seconds the source url of the iframe needs to change (only once).

I know that I need to use the select code below to determine when the user clicked on the tab but I do not know where to start. Thank you for your help. Any code help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select: function(event, ui)



 <div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="ahah_1.html"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_2.html"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_3.html"><span>Content 3</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does the iframe come into play?

Comment: document.getElementById("IframeId").src = "http://www.google.com" tried this maybe if i change the src of iframe. didnt help.

Comment: What I mean is, there's no iframe in the code you posted.  Is the iframe part of stuff returned by the ajax request?

Comment: <div id="Todo_Overview"> ... </div>

Comment: no it is not just looked at carefully now. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've done this.

Change the url like so using the built in function. Changing the url in the "a" tag won't do anything, because the link changes when it is bound to the tab layout.:

```
$("#tabdiv").tabs("url", tabIndex, newLink);
```

Now the url is updated, but the content stays the same, so refresh the tab like this:

```
$("#tabdiv").tabs("load", $("#tabdiv").tabs("option","selected"));
```

Or if you want to switch to another tab just do this:

```
$("#tabdiv").tabs("load", tabIndex);
```